# Travis CI cant resolve association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, travis-ci

I found an issue I cannot figure out what is wrong.
I am creating a rails app. I have some models joined by "join-models".

Locally if I run 'rspec' everything is working.
But if Travis CI runs the specs, it cant resolve the dependencies. And I got an error. What can I do to fix this?

This is the output from Travis CI:
[image]
[image]

And this is locally from my terminal.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a migration issue. The database against which your tests are running by Travis CI, does not have the `request_id` for the `BorrowRequest` model. That's why you got that error. But it works locally because you ran the migration locally.

So, all you need is to run the migration so that `request_id` column is added to the `borrow_requests` table in your database against which the Travis CI runs the test. That should fix your problem.

Comment: I thought travis is doing it automatically. How can I run migration on travis?

Comment: Yeah, ideally it should run the migrations for you when setup properly. Did it work before? Or, its your first time after configuring Travis CI?

Comment: You were right. I had an old schema.rb after updating it, travis is fine now